# Ação usando select

Tags: javascript, html5

Tenho um `select`

```
      <select class="select-sala" id="selecionar-aula">

        <option value="">Pagina 1</option>
        <option value="">Pagina 2</option>

      </select>
```

O que eu preciso é que quando eu selecione a `página 1` ele me envie para a url da Pagina 1 dinamicamente, sem que seja necessário clicar em um botão e assim também com a `página 2`.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou dar minha sugestão, sem precisar criar `<script>` mas colocando direto no `<select>`

**OBS:** Coloquei a primeira opção do `<select>` como "Selecionar", pois se já entrar com um `<option>` que tenha link, mesmo selecionando ele, vc não vai ser direcionado para a página. Então coloquei um "`placehoder`" no início.

Veja como ficou no exemplo

```css
select option[data-default] {
  color: #999; /* cor simulando que o campo está desabilitado depois que abre o select */
}
```

```html
<select name="forma" onchange="location = this.value;">
  <option selected data-default>- Selecione -</option>
  <option value="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/">StackOverflow</option>
  <option value="https://google.com/">Google</option>
  <option value="pagina-1.php">Página 1</option>
  <option value="pagina-2.html">Página 1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var select = document.getElementById('selecionar-aula');

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  window.location = select.value;
})
```

```html
<select class="select-sala" id="selecionar-aula">
  <option value="pagina1.html">Pagina 1</option>
  <option value="pagina2.html">Pagina 2</option>
</select>
```

Adicione um ouvinte de evento no select, pegue o se valor e redirecione para lá